# Change GET REQUEST header of an iframe via browser extension

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, iframe

after some serious googleing AFAIK, there is no way to change http request header of an iframe. Since that is VERY important for our application, is there a way to do it via browser extensions (Firefox would be enough)?

Thanks.

Comment: To make things more clear, I should be able to adjust user agent in javascript and that should tell extension to change UA, or at least add a new variable to http header like X-User-Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long while...

1) Install Mozilla SDK:
[Addons SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation)

Follow instructions to create extension directory structure

2) In your lib/main.js script:

```
 17 var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
 18 var data = require("sdk/self").data;
 19 var _header = "";
 20 
 21 
 22 // Define observer
 23 var httpRequestObserver =
 24 {
 25     observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
 26         if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
 27             var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
 28             httpChannel.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", _header, false);
 29         }
 30     }
 31 };
 32 
 33 // Register observer
 34 var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
 35                                 .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
 36 
 37 observerService.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-modify-request", false);
 38 
 39 var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
 40 
 41 pageMod.PageMod({
 42     include: ["*"],
 43     contentScriptFile: data.url("content.js"),
 44     onAttach: function(worker) {
 45         worker.on("message", function(message) {
 46             _header = message;
 47         }); 
 48     }   
 49 });
```

3) Then in your data/content.js short snippet:

```
  1 document.defaultView.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  2 
  3     //alert(event.data);
  4 
  5     self.postMessage(event.data);
  6 
  7 }, false);
```

4) And finally in your page's script you just make simple call:

```
window.postMessage("CONST_STR;" + data.foo + ";" + data.bar, "*");
```

Since it's pretty complex beast, one should really go and RTFM for better understanding, otherwise if you can just pass with this, even better, you'll won't have an urge for drug or drink.

Hope it helps someone, somewhere...